# Running java file that has a package (on Linux)

Tags: java, linux, class, package

I am trying to run a program that I wrote which uses the package `net.codejava.sound`. I can compile the file, but when I try to run it I get the error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class AudioPlayerExample1 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/codejava/sound/AudioPlayerExample1 (wrong name: AudioPlayerExample1)`

I know it has something to do with the package and I tried running it like this 
`java -cp . net.codejava.sound.AudioPlayerExample1`, but it didn't work. I am a beginner so please help. The file in on my Desktop and called `AudioPlayerExample1.java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your project and your java version. If you only have the one file, have java 11+ installed, and no dependencies you should be able to just run `java AudioPlayerExample1.java`

Comment: oh thank you, I was trying ```java AudioPlayerExample1``` not ```AudioPlayerExample1.java```. Usually it just works without the ```.java```